# Looping through perl array prints memory address

Tags: perl

I am looping through a perl array but it is only printing the memory address.

```
my $my_session_data = {
 rows => {
    locations => [],
  }
};

my $data_row = [12, 55, '/home/pi/Desktop', undef];
push(@{$my_session_data->{rows}{locations}}, $data_row);
$data_row = [12, 36, '/home/pi/codes', undef];
push(@{$my_session_data->{rows}{locations}}, $data_row);
```

my loop is:

```
foreach my $element ($my_session_data->{rows}{locations}) {
    print $element;
}
```

which prints out a memory address.

When I do a dump of the data.

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        12,
        55,
        '/home/pi/Desktop',
        undef
      ],
      [
        12,
        55,
        '/home/pi/code',
        undef
      ],
      [
        12,
        55,
        '/home/pi/state',
        undef
      ]
    ];
```

I've also tried `foreach my $element ($my_session_data->{rows}->{locations})` and `foreach my $element ($my_session_data->{rows}->{locations}[0])` they all produce memory addresses.
I think it should be the same as looping through an array however its only printing the memory address.  When I `ref $my_session_data->{rows}{locations}` prints array.

Comment: You need to dereference the array reference: Try `foreach my $element (@{$my_session_data->{rows}{locations}}) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know if this is the correct way to go about it but I had to deference the `$element`.  `for my $item (@$element){..}`.  Why do I have to deference?

Comment: The syntax of the `for` loop is described in [perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops) : `for VAR (LIST) BLOCK` so you need specify a list. A reference is interpreted as a list of a single element, namely the reference value itself. To iterate over the list of element in the array that the reference refers to, you need to dereference it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looping through a perl array but it is only printing the memory address.
>   [...]
>   `foreach my $element ($my_session_data->{rows}{locations}) {`

The syntax of the `for` loop is described in [perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops) :

```
LABEL for VAR (LIST) BLOCK
```

so you need to specify a `LIST` of items that you want to iterate over. A reference is interpreted as a 
list of a single element, namely the reference value itself. To iterate over the list of element in the array that the reference refers to, you need to dereference it. Example:

```
$ perl -E '$ar = [1..3]; for my $item ($ar, $ar) { say $item }'
ARRAY(0x5596f7f2d780)
ARRAY(0x5596f7f2d780)
$ perl -E '$ar = [1..3]; for my $item (@$ar) { say $item }'
1
2 
3
```

So for your use case it would be:

```
foreach my $element (@{$my_session_data->{rows}{locations}}) { ... }
```